# Google Site Search XML API Pagination

Tags: pagination, google-search, google-search-api

I am using the Google Site Search XML API and want to do pagination. I know that the count in  is considered inaccurate, but how does Google implement their paging on the demo site at http://www.google.com/sitesearch/? It seems to at least be accurately knowing if there are more than 35 results to break into the 8 pages.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I've just implemented this myself so thought I should share.

Not sure what language you are using, but here's how I did it in PHP (`$xml` is, of course, the full XML result retrieved using curl or file_get_contents or whatever):

```
$results_per_page = 8;
$pages = ceil($xml->RES->M/$results_per_page);

if ($pages > 1) {
   for ($i = 0; $i < $pages; $i++) { 
      $class = '';
      if ( ($i) * $results_per_page == $_GET['s']) {
          $class = 'current-page';
      }                                                    
      echo '<a href="?q=' . $searchterms . '&amp;s=' . $i * $results_per_page . '" class="pagenum '. $class . '"><strong>' . $i + 1 . '</strong></a>
   }
}
```

Note that $results_per_page should match the value of `num` in the XML url that's fetched